# Unfairly charged by Iberia: what recourse do I have?

Tags: cancellations, refunds, iberia

Iberia has unfairly charged me 60 euros of cancellation fees, directly contradicting their earlier promise, and their website does not have obvious ways to complain. What recourse do I have?

Details:

- I needed to make a booking and transport a pet animal in the cabin. *Before* booking the flight, I called customer service, and asked about the process, while mentioning the exact flight I was planning to book. I was told that I can only add the animal transport service after I have already completed the booking. I asked, what if adding this service is not possible for some reason, can a solution be found at no cost to me, for example by changing the flight date? *I was reassured that this will be possible, at no additional cost to me.*
- I made the booking, and immediately called customer service again, to add the service, just as instructed. I was told that adding the service is not possible for this flight, nor can the booking / flight date be changed to one that allows animal transport. After a long back and forth, the only solution they offered was cancelling the booking at 30€ cost to me.  I was told very clearly (no chance of misunderstanding) that the booking was cancelled and I'd get the refund—sans the 30€—within 24 hours.
- Not trusting them, I called again the next day to confirm that the booking is indeed cancelled, but now I was told that it actually wasn't. I asked again to cancel it. This time I got a case number and I was told that the refund comes in not in 24 hours, but in 5-7 days.
- After 8 days, no refund came in so I had to call again. Refund appeared only after 10 days, but only half of the sum was refunded (one passenger out of two on the booking).
- Called again, and to get the complete refund for the ticket, I was charged another 30€ fee, now the total coming to 60€. I got another case number. I was told that I can put in a complaint [on their website](https://www.iberia.com/es/customer-relations/), but in reality this is not possible. First, this section of the website is for claims only, not complaints, second, it doesn't work (server error).

Do I have any recourse after this amount of mistreatment, and getting unfairly charged? Can I get my 60€ back? My conversations with customer support must have been recorded: I gave explicit permission to record it each time. But only they have those recordings, not me.

Comment: Or do we just have to accept that this sort of thing is just an unavoidable risk of air travel these days? All airlines I checked, without exception, had a rating between 1.0 and 1.5 on TrustPilot.

Comment: Can you dispute the charge with your credit card company?

Comment: What is your country of residence, and what was your itinerary (just the airports of flight numbers)? This may have an influence on what can be done and how.

Comment: Don't read too much into ratings on random websites. The vast majority of travellers has an uneventful trip but doesn't ever bother to post a rating. The minority that runs into trouble will disproportionately frequently post a one-star rating. It's nothing like hotel bookings where ratings are actively solicited so that you get a sort-of-reasonable sample.

Comment: @jcaron Are you thinking of the EU compensation rules, which depend on whether the flight ends/starts in the EU? My impression is that this isn't covered by that. I'm trying to fly from Berlin to Reykjavik with a small parrot, which makes Iberia my only option. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181096/1293 Vueling has appropriate flights, but won't allow booking this route on a single ticket.  Iberia is sadly the only airline I could find that (claims to) provide the service I am looking for.

Comment: Most likely I can not do anything at all, since I cannot prove what happened and what was said during the conversations with customer service. Of course they only provide phone support, so I have no written records. What's really frustrating is that there was in fact a better way to proceed here, but they only told me about it much later. It turns out that one can do a "pre-booking" for only 10€, though this is neither advertised nor discoverable. One has to go all the way to the payment step during a booking process, then click the link to go back to the homepage of their website.

Comment: At that point a prompt will come up trying to convince the would-be customer not to abandon the booking, but do a pre-booking instead. But there is no direct way, as far as I can tell, to go directly for the pre-booking.